# Download entire webpage as HTML (including the HTML assets) without save as pop up using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pyautogui, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to scrape a website and download all the webpages as .html files (including all the HTML assets) so that the locally downloaded page opens just like the same in the server.

Currently using Selenium, Chrome Webdriver, and Python.

**Approach:**

I tried updating the prefs of the chrome browser. And then login into the website. After logging in I want to download the webpage similarly we do download by clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> from the keyboard.

Below code opens the desired page I want to download but does not disable Windows's save as a pop-up and neither downloads the page to the specified path.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pyautogui


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {
"download.default_directory":"C:\\Users\\pathtodir",           
"download.prompt_for_download": False,             
"download.directory_upgrade": True,             
"safebrowsing.enabled": True
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(***URL to the website***)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="id_username"]').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="id_password"]').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="datagrid-0"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').click()

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
pyautogui.typewrite('hello1' + '.html')   
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

Can somebody please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? Please suggest if there is any other alternative library that can be used in python.

Answer (score 1):

To save a page first obtain the page source behind the webpage with the help of the `page_source` method.

Then open a file with a particular encoding with the `codecs.open` method. The file has to be opened in the write mode represented by w and encoding type as **utf−8**. Then use the write method to write the content obtained from the **page_source** method.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

driver.get(***URL to the website***)
h = driver.page_source

n=os.path.join("C:\ANYPATH","Page.html")
f = codecs.open(n, "w", "utf−8")

f.write(h)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for responding. I tried out your code. However, it is downloading the source code for me but not the HTML assets(CSS, JS file). So, when I open the downloaded file in the browser, it is not the same as we view it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue, the problem was that my code quit before the browser was able to download the file. Adding `time.sleep()` fixed it.

Updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pyautogui

driver.get(***URL to the website***)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="id_username"]').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="id_password"]').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="datagrid-0"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').click()
FILE_NAME = r'C:\ANYPATH\Page.html'
pyautogui.typewrite(FILE_NAME)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```